# Three.JS with Streaming

Tags: sockets, three.js

I have the following problem, I want to render on the server side a 3D model, then I need to send the rendered file over socket.IO to the client. So at the moment I realized the 3D model rendering on the server side and also the sending over socket.IO to the client.

So far so good. But now when I convert my canvas on the server side to base 64 encoding to transmit the 2D picture to the client, this converting from 3D to base64 encoding takes to long. My 3D model starts to jerk.

Is there another possibility to transmit the 3D rendered model to the client which is faster? Or can I boost the converting on the server side? That the 3D model don't jerk?

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: By render you mean to a bitmap image, correct? You can do this rendering outside of Three.JS and update a standard <img> element. Then use this element as a texture within Three.JS. I've seen some examples of this done (one with a video element, which may be better for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this JavaScript library to capture the screen image
http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.screenshot.html